# error: not found: value StructType/StructField/StringType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running scala on my local machine, version 2.0.

```
val schema = StructType(schemaString.split("|^").map(fieldName =>StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
<console>:45: error: not found: value StructType
   val schema = StructType(schemaString.split("|^").map(fieldName =>StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
                ^
<console>:45: error: not found: value StructField
   val schema = StructType(schemaString.split("|^").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
                                                                     ^
<console>:45: error: not found: value StringType
   val schema = StructType(schemaString.split("|^").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
                                                                                            ^
```

i loaded import org.apache.spark.sql._ but still getting this error. am i missing any packages?

Comment: try importing `org.apache.spark.sql.types._`, that's where these classes are...

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
```

try importing

Comment: Is StructField can be  FloatType or DoubleType?